# Create B-Lymphocyte picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create B-Lymphocyte picture (antigen) and i would like to know if someone could give me a start point (e.g. online examples, etc.).

Here are some examples of what i would like to create:

[image: Antigens]

[image: Antibody]

Regards

Comment: Can you link to a picture of the type you would like to create (for those of us not sure what a B-Lymphocyte looks like)?

Comment: Inkscape? (http://inkscape.org/)

Answer (score 1):

There is an illustration of a B-Lymphocyte at the [B cell Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_cell). You can find general tikz examples at [TikZ and PGF examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).

When you know what you want to achieve, consult the [TikZ manual](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) which is very well written. If you have further specific questions, do not hestitate to ask here.